# How to resolve this conflict of two JSON.net existing?

Tags: c#, json.net, visual-studio-2013

I updated json.net in all projects in my solution and after I get this error:

> The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' exists in both
>   '\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and
>   'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Why is it trying to load json.net from the Blend folder and how do I get around this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Delete the duplicate reference.

Comment: @SLaks It's only referenced once in my project. Are you suggesting I deleting it from one location in the file system?

Comment: No.  Where are you getting that error?

Comment: Always painful and hard to diagnose.  You might want to take advantage of [this new feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: As a workaround until the [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816985/newtonsoft-dll-conflicts-between-visual-studio-12-0-blend-and-mvc-5-web-project-after-vs-2013-update-1-install) is resolved, you could rename the version in the Blend folder.

Answer (score 38):

In my case, the problem was that there were two references to two different versions of Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my project. This wasn't apparent by looking at the references in the Solution tree view: you have to examine the csproj file.

To fix this:

1. right-click the project in Visual Studio, and select Unload Project
2. search the MSBuild file for references to Newtonsoft.Json
3. delete the reference the older version of the library
4. right-click the project and reload it.

Comment: I have a third party SDK DLL that is causing this error in my solution now.  It's using a much older version of Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert - how should I handle that?  My code has been established for a long time and has many references to this, to have to force my code to use an older version would be horrible to me.

Comment: Specifically: The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both 'CSSNWebServiceSDK, Version=1.0.6005.12454, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21547a501d0bdb4b' and 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' - unfortunately I only have one reference to newtonsoft in my csproj and i can't remove the other DLL :(

Comment: The post was ins 2014, I'm in 2018 and we still have this issue on Visual Studio. Thank you. Fix my problem

Comment: Felipe Oriani, I'm in 2019 ;)  I fixed the problem by editing my .csproj file and removing the old reference to Newtonsoft

Comment: Here it is 2020 and I am experiencing this same problem.  I have a project that references version 12 but some NuGet packages from Microsoft referenced in the larger solution are still referencing the Newtonsoft version 6.0 and when combined this error shows up.  If I remove the Microsoft packages
 it goes away but then I can't build the larger project.  No solution as yet.

Comment: For me it was in CSPROJ file (unload, right click on project and choose Edit) and I just made all the versions the same and it worked. It was on two different places and there were two different DLLs.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just used the fully qualified name of the assembly:

var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert...

(VS Community 2017 version 15.7.5)