# Error:The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' exists in both \Bin\Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.dll and \Bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

/* If I am building after deleting Newtonsoft.Json.dll then It works fine but after clean and build getting the same error?*/

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using localhost;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using BusinessLayerGDS.Model;
using BusinessLayerGDS.BAL;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;



**And The codes:**
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject objActualData=Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(strResponse);
```

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

Comment: I tried this too.

Comment: you have two references of the same dll may be of different version.

Comment: How can I come out from the error permanently as I am able to get the temprary solution by deleting Newtonsoft.Json.dll file and then build(It works).

Comment: You have to check  `csproj file` and delete the `dll` with old version.

Comment: But If I am going for clean and build then again the file is being added and I m getting the same error.

Comment: You need to check first `csproj file`

Comment: I m not getting any csproj file.

Comment: as there are many so confused.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637424/how-to-resolve-this-conflict-of-two-json-net-existing?rq=1`

Comment: Are you sure that these dll's are same only version is different.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.Net20.dll.

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` exists in both so you need to delete the one. Error is self explanatory.

Comment: The error is self explanatory but It's being added everytime after clean and build.

Comment: I am unable to stop that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Or where this folder is in your computer:
>
**Temporary ASP.NET Files**

I have seen some people configuring it under:

> *c:\Users[youruserid]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files*

Or you may be using a different .net version than v4.0.30319

Inside this folder you may find some odd folder names one of those is the folder of your application, you need to find which on it is then you should delete what's inside the **bin**

If some files or folders are locked you may need to stop your IIS or IIS Express.

Go to back and rebuild your application; it should work fine then

Comment: In my experience, you DONT want to do this - It will just keep on looking and if you have another version somewhere, itl use that one. Fix the .csproj file with a text editor - and be sure to look good for the HINTPATH, as it can have multiple places defined.

Comment: @user1515791 There is nothing wrong in doing this. Unless of course you can show us otherwise but in "**my experience**" this works like a charm

Comment: Well, in my case the issue was because the project file's reference to the assembly is invalid - despite of using nuget and bindingredirects. So itll just use the first assembly it can find on the file system. By removing 1 thats causing problems is just waiting for the next (or updating, installing something else, etc) The reason (for me) was the invalid hintpath, fix that and the problem is gone, not the symptom. But, i offcourse cannot know that's exactly the same problem you experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Close VS

Open your .csproj file with a text editor

Look for all the hintpath tags for Newtonsoft

```
<HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
```

Fix the hintpaths ALL - look carefully, it can be configured at multiple locations and Nuget was not bulletproof for me anyawy.